# Can i do the render method or the return html of react component in a html file?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

Can I take the `render` method if we talk about components, or the return of a React hook html and put it in a separate html file like angular?

My tsx files are getting so big and would look much cleaner to put the html lines in a whole different file.

Comment: you could always break it up into more, smaller reusable components, which can of course live in their own files.

Answer (score 0):

Since React use the principle of a virtual DOM it's not possible to move the html in separate file. Best think that you can do is to move the `tsx` in a separate file like this:

**tsx file:**

```
import React from 'react';

export const HelloWorld = () => {
    return (
        <div>Hello World !</div>
    )
}
```

**Import and use it:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld';

export class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { };
}

render() {
    return (
        <HelloWorld />
    )
}
}
```